# How to call leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt on setEdit call?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I ran into the problem that I need to invoke swipes for all cells except the last one by calling SetEdit. That is, I click on the Edit button, a number of cells are shifted to the right and their actions are shown. They should be static in this position and you can, for example, click on deleting or editing a cell. Is this even possible?

I have already tried a lot of things, but I could not even achieve the result.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please share some code? or some more details?

Comment: Hi there, please read this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. Then put some code so we can help you with your code.